# How to fill the NaN values with the values contains in another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find if the split column contains anything from the class list. If yes, I want to update the category column using the values from the class list. The desired category is my optimal goal.

[sampledata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eenfm.png)

```
domain      split   Category    Desired Category
abc@XYT.com XYT.com Null         XYT
abb@XTY.com XTY.com Null         Null
abc@ssa.com ssa.com Null         ssa
bbb@bbc.com bbc.com Null         bbc
ccc@abk.com abk.com Null         abk
acc@ssb.com ssb.com Null         ssb
            
Class=['NaN','XYT','ssa','abk','abc','def','asds','ssb','bbc','XY','ab']    



for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for x in class:
        intersection=row.split.contains(x)
        if intersection:
           df.loc[index,'class'] = intersection
```

Just cannot get it right

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: Pleas include the code you've tried. Are you using pandas? Have you read the Excel into a DataFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.extract`. Create a regular expression that will match one of the words in the list and extract the word will match (or NaN if none).

**Update**: As the '|' operator is never greedy even if it would produce a longer overall match, you have to reverse sort your list manually.

```
lst = ['NaN','XY','ab','XYT','ssa','abk','abc','def','asds','ssb','bbc']
lst = sorted(lst, reverse=True)
pat = fr"({'|'.join(lst)})"

df['Category'] = df['split'].str.extract(pat)
```

```
>>> df
        domain    split Category
0  abc@XYT.com  XYT.com      XYT
1  abb@XTY.com  XTY.com      NaN
2  abc@ssa.com  ssa.com      ssa
3  bbb@bbc.com  bbc.com      bbc
4  ccc@abk.com  abk.com      abk
5  acc@ssb.com  ssb.com      ssb

>>> lst
['ssb', 'ssa', 'def', 'bbc', 'asds', 'abk', 'abc', 'ab', 'XYT', 'XY', 'NaN']

>>> pat
'(ssb|ssa|def|bbc|asds|abk|abc|ab|XYT|XY|NaN)'
```

Comment: Awesome result. it works for most of the data but wouldd give me XY instead of  XYT.
I updated my class list in the question. Thanks for the workaround

Comment: I have the same result with the new class list? OK. it's because `XY` is before `XYT`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes XY is before XYT. Do you know how to fix that. Thanks! That's really close

Comment: BOOM!!! It is working, can you specify why reverse helps. It orders in which order?

Comment: For the reason I explain in my answer. The regex engine matches the first occurrence of a word. If you do not reverse sort your list and 'XY' is before 'XYT', the last one will never match anything. In your case, you should sort in reverse lexicographic order to have longest words before shortest words.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there can only be a maximum of one match, try:

```
df["Category"] = df["split"].apply(lambda x: " ".join(c for c in Class if c in x))

>>> df
        domain    split Category
0  abc@XYT.com  XYT.com   XYT
1  abc@XTY.com  XTY.com      
2  abc@ssa.com  ssa.com   ssa
3  bbb@bbc.com  bbc.com   bbc
4  ccc@abk.com  abk.com   abk
5  acc@ssb.com  ssb.com   ssb
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It almost worked. Unfortunately, there's more than one match in my dataset.
Let me update the class.

Class=['NaN','XYT','ssa','abk','abc','def','asds','ssb','bbc','X]  
The resulting category looks like X XYT. But from column split, I want XYT only.

Comment: What if you had [“X”, “XY”, “XYT”] in Class? Which should match and why? What is the logic for choosing either one?